# displayDialogAsync in Word online not documenting close action / broken behavior different from Word Online to Word for Mac

Tags: javascript, office-js

I am getting the following message in the console when I close a dialog in Word Online:

```
Unknown conversation Id.
```

Rather than getting a code I can process I just get that...

(macOS / Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Same code (running from localhost and a sideloaded manifest) running on Word for Mac 16.13.1 (180523) - slow build - results in dialog windows that don't function properly...When closed they don't fire off a code I can use and Javascript does not seem to run in them. When I try to inspect the dialog I get a manic flickering of the window and the console does not open.

Overall feels like something is wrong with the displayDialogAsync API.

Here is an example dialog creation snippet:

```
$('.integrateQuotes').click(function(){
    console.log('Clicking quote machine choice...');
    var dialogUrl = 'https://localhost/AnnotateX/qWord/modules/integratequotes.html';
    var dialog = null;   //  dialogwindow object
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(dialogUrl, {height: 80, width: 80, displayInIframe: true}, function (asyncResult){
        dialog = asyncResult.value;
        error = asyncResult.error;
        status = asyncResult.status;
        console.log('Result from dialog window...error: ') +  + console.log(' and status: ') + console.log(status) + console.log(dialog);
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
    });
  });
  self.location.href = '#writingDiv';
```

And processMessage:

```
function processMessage(arg) {
    // var messageFromDialog = JSON.parse(arg.message);
    // showUserName(messageFromDialog.name);
    console.log('processing message from dialog: ') + console.log(arg);

    // switch (arg.error) {
    //      case 12002:
    //          console.log("The dialog box has been directed to a page that it cannot find or load, or the URL syntax is invalid.");
    //          break;
    //      case 12003:
    //          console.log("The dialog box has been directed to a URL with the HTTP protocol. HTTPS is required.");            break;
    //      case 12006:
    //          console.log("Dialog closed.");
    //          break;
    //      default:
    //          console.log("Unknown error in dialog box.");
    //          break;
    //   }

    // dialog.close();
    if (arg.message === 'easyBib'){
      //Now open URL
      var win = window.open('http://www.easybib.com/cite/results?source=website&provider=&cite-style=mla7&query=' + localStorage.easyBib);
      console.log("Sending to easyBib: " + localStorage.easyBib);
      if (win) {
          //Browser has allowed it to be opened
          win.focus();
      } else {
          //Browser has blocked it
          alert('Please allow popups for this website');
      }
    } else {
      dialog.close();
      self.location.href = '#writingDiv';
    }
    // self.location.href = 'qResearch.html';
    // window.location.replace("/qResearch.html");
    // window.location.href = "/newPage.html";
}
```

I'm going to try on Windows now...but something

Answer (score 1):

To handle the event of a user closing the dialog, you need a handler for the DialogEventReceived event, not DialogMessageReceived. There's more at: [Using a Dialog with Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out...and maybe there are too many issues in this question. Javascript should still run (if it works in Word Online it should work on macOS latest Word).

For instance, if I open a dialog window, close it (using the 'x'), then try to reopen

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out...and maybe there are too many issues in this question. 

I have updated my code and while I still get the 'conversation ID' message in my console using Word Online, the windows are operating as intended in Word Online.

Using macOS Word 2016 (slow build details above) the window opens once but does not message the parent on user close. The dialog still exists, and so if you try to reopen you get a 'dialog already exists' message.

Comment: Additionally, javascript is not running on the dialog when it does open. Very much looks like broken functionality in this latest version of Word. Similar issues: 
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example/issues/6

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/74211d2c-e9b5-4ddf-ad2c-5c11d59e79d8/displaydialogasync-messageparent-not-working?forum=outlookdev